# send string to atmega32 through bluetooth hc-05 module

Tags: string, bluetooth, hc-05, atmega32

If I want to send a string like " Hello World" from a mobile phone to a Bluetooth HC-05 module, then how to handle this string and make my logic accordingly ...? Is there any function to convert string to char? I am using an ATmega32 microcontroller to control HC-05.

Comment: By "mobile phone," do you mean Android specifically? There is way for an HC-05 to communicate with an iPhone app. For Android, see https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth In particular you'll want https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth/transfer-data. On the HC-05 side, any tutorial is going to be fine (talking to Android is the same as talking to Arduino)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can create an array to receive the command in the function of microcontroller side. By the way, which app are you using for testing your Bluetooth module? I recommend you use this one: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.clarence.bluetoothserial, with which you can customize your frequently used commands as buttons. It’s very convenient.